# Closedness of two subsets of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

Why is $A=\{(x ,1/x)$ $|$ $0< x \leq 1\}$  closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Whereas  $A=\{(x,\sin(1/x))$ $|$ $0< x \leq 1\}$  is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: For the second case, I suggest you to draw a graph of $\sin(1/x)$ (e.g. use wolfram alpha to do so) to see why it is not closed.

Comment: What should I be looking for?

Comment: A closed set would contains all its limit points. But from the picture you will find out it is not true. By then you can try to give a mathematical proof.

Comment: Try to understand why the first is closed first, it's not that obvious: a set defined as $f(x)$ for $0< x\leq 1$ is not closed in general.

Comment: I am really not too sure. Is it because $1/x$ is continuous and it's being mapped from a closed interval?

Comment: It is true that $\sin(1/x)$ is very misbehaved as $x \to 0$, but suppose the second set is $\{(x,\sin(x)) : 0<x\leq 1\}$; this is still not closed. However, unlike the example I just gave, the fact that $\sin(1/x)$ is so wild near $x=0$ means that there are many points in the closure of the second set given that are not, in fact, in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Big Hint:* Convince yourself that if you take a sequence $x_n \in (0,1]$ such that $(x_n, 1/x_n)$ converges to some point $(y_1, y_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $y_2 = 1/y_1$ and $y_1 \in (0,1]$. This will mean that any convergent sequence made from elements of $A_1 = \{(x,1/x) : 0 < x \leq 1\}$ converges in $A_1$, and hence it is closed. On the other hand, suppose that you take $x_n = \frac{1}{\pi n}$. Then $(x_n, \sin(1/x_n)) \to (0,0) \notin A_2$. So you have found a sequence of elements in $A_2 = \{(x, \sin(1/x)) : 0<x\leq 1\}$ which converge, but do not converge to an element in $A_2$. This proves that $A_2$ is not closed.